# Convert .mkv file into .mp4 file in swift 3

Tags: swift, mp4, avassetexportsession, mkv

I want to convert a .mkv file into .mp4 file, I searched a lot but did not get any solution for this.

I used below code to convert but the code not works, always getting the following error.

> "Export failed: Cannot Open"

```
func convertVideoToMP4(_ videoURL: URL)  {
        let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL, options: nil)

        let startDate = Foundation.Date()

        //Create Export session
        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
        let documentsDirectory2 = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL

        let filePath = documentsDirectory2.appendingPathComponent("rendered-Video.mp4")
        deleteFile(filePath)
        exportSession!.outputURL = filePath
        exportSession!.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
        exportSession!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, 0)
        let range = CMTimeRangeMake(start, avAsset.duration)
        exportSession?.timeRange = range

        exportSession!.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
            switch exportSession!.status {
            case .failed:
                print("Export failed: \(String(describing: exportSession?.error?.localizedDescription))")
            case .cancelled:
                print("Export canceled")
            case .completed:
                //Video conversion finished
                print("Successful!")
            default:
                break
            }
        })
 }
```

Comment: Try replacing `rendered-Video.mp4` with `rendered_Video.mp4`

Comment: What url you are passing in this method while calling?
Where your .mkv file is stored?

Comment: What's inside the MKV container?

Comment: whats the need behind conversion ?

Comment: @PramodKumarSaxena .mkv file store in document directory and am passing this file url in convertVideoToMP4() function parameter.

Comment: @Vaibhav I downloaded this file from Twilio server in .mkv file format and need to store this file in photos library, but am not able to store this file in Photos Library, that's the reason I want to convert this file into .mp4 format and store it to Photos Library.

Comment: standard way conversion takes place from server side, just tell your server team to send the video url in .mp4 format or .mov, both are supportable for photo lib.

Comment: Crete `URL` with `URL(fileURLWithPath: "<your doc. dir, url>")`, that will pass in you method.

Comment: @PramodKumarSaxena Yes, I am passing the same URL in it.