# how to add mkv file in avasset and extract video and audio from that?(swift)

Tags: swift, video, swiftui, h.264, mkv

i want to extract mkv's video and audio in AVasset and merge it in mp4 container and display it in swift UI?

i tried this [Convert .mkv file into .mp4 file in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45568486/convert-mkv-file-into-mp4-file-in-swift-3) but that's does not worked